# Apache internal redirect limit reached

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, httpd, rewritecond

I have following problem:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

The apache tries to reach non-existing files.

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine  on

Options +FollowSymlinks    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/$   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1   

RewriteRule ^\??$ index.php [L]
```

I'v turned on logs and in logs there was like:

```
/nonexistingfile -> /subfolder/nonexistingfile
/subfolder/nonexistingfile -> subfodler/subfolder/nonexistingfile 
/subfodler/subfolder/nonexistingfile -> subfodler/subfodler/subfolder/nonexistingfile
```

And like this 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

Add `[L]`  to the line where you rewrite to subfolder.

Comment: But when mod_rewrite fill decide to stop rule processing? Would the last rule be executed?